# How can I pass an SQLiteDatabase variable through an intent?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to get a reference to my database in one activity, and pass the referred database variable to another Activity through an intent. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: why do you have to do it?you can create a new object instead..?

Comment: You can pass it through your adapter if using listview just like usual?

Comment: What you want exactly? Please describe in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a method in your Sqlite class to get Singleton object of that class :

```
public static synchronized SQLiteDatabaseHandler getInstance(Context mContext) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SQLiteDatabaseHandler(mContext);
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

> You can get Object of this class in any of your classes (no need to
>   pass SqliteDatabaseHandler Object to another class) :

```
SQLiteDatabaseHandler.getInstance(mContext);
```